# Improve productivity when working on a shared salt-stack repository with multiple team members?

Tags: salt-stack

My team uses salt-stack to manage our fleet of servers. Currently we have a single master, and two GitHub repositories for our SLS logic and Pillar data. The issue is when a team member needs to do work they have to "checkout" the salt master so that they can work uninterrupted on their branch. My question is, what are some better ways to solve this problem so that we can have multiple team members working on multiple branches without having to checkout the master?

One thing I've thought of is setting up multi-master so that we may have multiple "development" salt masters and then a true salt master that we execute automation from.

Any thoughts or feedback on the setup is welcomed!

Answer (score 1):

one thing to do is separate out the dev, test, and prod environments completely like you are thinking. this will at least separate the prod environment from any testing accidents. next thing. implement localized develop systems. such as using kitchen-salt or local vms with mini versions of your dev environment. this will at least make development time faster as they are not relying on the centralized dev system that should be saved more more developed code, and is more for testing integration instead of overall development. if possible get a ci/cd system that can spin up tests against pr's to the git repos. that way you are testing the changes before you test the merge. basically `local dev`->`PR`->`dev`->`test`->`prod` with testing at each step.